# Facebook Ads API - get instagram ad post's replies

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/'.$effective_instagram_story_id.'/comments?fields=created_at,id,message,instagram_user{id,username}&access_token='.$access_token
```

This api method returns only top-level comments, but I need to get replies too. How to achieve this?

Comment: do you mean in one call, or in general?

Comment: Both types. But one call is more prior